# Trouble with pairs() function in nlme

Tags: r, nlme

I am having trouble getting the `pairs()` function to work in `nlme`. Take this example from Pinhiero and Bates *Mixed-Effects Models in S and S-Plus*.

The model itself runs just fine

```
fm1Theo.lis <- nlsList(conc ~ SSfol(Dose, Time, lKe, lKa, lCl), data = Theoph)
```

But the pairs plot...

```
pairs(fm1Theo.lis, id = 0.1)
```

...returns this error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class "c("nlsList", "lmList")" to a data.frame
```

I also tried

```
pairs(fm1Theo.lis, ~ ranef(., level = 2), id = 0.1)
```

But get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. What you get is the same as running `pairs.default(fm1Theo.lis, id = 0.1)`, which would suggest that `nlme` isn't loaded, but then it's not clear how `fm1Theo.lis` works. What about `nlme:::pairs.lmList(fm1Theo.lis, id = 0.1)`?

Comment: Thanks @Julius Vainora. I think it was some sort of `nlme` loading error, because all the pairs plots in my scripts worked before. I should have remembered the advice from Roy in the IT crowd and turned my computer (or RStudio in this case) off and on again. Because now it is working. Still don't know what happened but it seems to be working now, the `pairs` plots are running.

Comment: While the fix is clear, in my answer I tried to explain the process of how one can resolve this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how one may think in this case. The error

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("nlsList", "lmList")’ to a data.frame
```

says that some object of class `c("nlsList", "lmList")` is being coerced to a data frame. Now since `fm1Theo.lis` is the result of using `nlsList`, it seems that the object in the error is indeed `nlsList`. That means that `pairs` does not know what to do with objects of such class. To confirm this, we can run

```
pairs.default(fm1Theo.lis, id = 0.1)
```

which is what is going to happen when no specific method for `fm1Theo.lis` is found. Indeed the error is the same. In one way or another confirming that `nlsList` and comes from `nlme`, it becomes clear that the issue is with loading the `nlme` package. Loading it or restarting the session then is almost surely going to help.